# Any way we can access redux state value from older action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to check if there is a way we can access older state values from a different action as the reducer always returns new state.

For example, there are 3 actions and in each action, a new state has been created.
Is there a way we can access  1st action state object from a 3rd reducer action.

Basically, my requirement is to reset the state to a state value from different action in the lifecycle.

Comment: As one option you can perhaps look into using Immutable.JS and storing the state before updating it.

Comment: I believe you'll just have to store a copy of the 'old' state

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is **Time Travel in Redux**, which is one of the core feature provided by Redux.

See this video from Dan https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsSnOQynTHs where it is explained.

To implement what you are trying you will need to **maintain multiple state in your application**.

Lets call them as past, present and future.

- Past: The application before action 1 is triggered.
- Present: The current state of application.
- Future: The future state of application after action 2 is triggered.

So your state will basically look like this:

```
ApplicationState= {
  past: {},
  present: {},
  future: {},
}
```

Now, If you want to travel back in time ie equivalent to accessing Past state.

```
switch(action.type){
  case "ACTIONTYPE_1":
   return {
     ...state,
     past: {...state},
     present: //implemention of logic
   }
}
```

I found a nice reading on [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-manage-state-with-redux-p4-david-geary/index.html) for what you are trying to achieve. Please have a look at it.